# Can we modify an existing site collection to become a host named site collection

Tags: host-header, host-named

I have 2 different site collections hosted on a SharePoint 2010 farm. I have created two different domain names in the DNS pointing to the SharePoint web server.

My question is despite reading numerous articles on msdn blogs or technet , there are virtually no references of modifying an existing site collection to become a host named site collection.

Is it even possible to change an existing path based site collection to a host-named site collection ?

The current path based site urls looks like this :-

```
http://serverhostname/sites/hr
```

The hostnamed site collection url needs to be

```
http://hr.mycompanyname.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this planning guide, the only way to do it is to do a backup and restore. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx. (Nearly at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Convert standard site collections to host-named site collections - thats the exact thing I missed in the article before. Thanks CMN !